# Truncate SQL date-time to date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I've been trying to write a query to get the counts of entries to an Oracle database on specific days. The issue is that the last modified date in the database is in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and I need it in the format yyyy-mm-dd so it counts the occurrences per day, not per second. When I truncate and cast the date, the query has been returning the format yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 and still not aggregating the counts per day. My query is shown bellow. I've been running variations of it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), TRUNC(CAST(LASTMODIFIED AS DATE)) 
FROM LEADEXTENSIONS 
GROUP BY LASTMODIFIED 
ORDER BY LASTMODIFIED DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type; it has `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and both always have year, month, day, hour, minute and second components (`TIMESTAMP` can, optionally, also have fractional seconds and time zone components).

Given this `CAST( lastmodified AS DATE )` is not going to do anything as you will cast the value from a `DATE` data type to a `DATE` data type.

What you need to do is `TRUNC`ate the `DATE` value, which will set the hour, minute and second components of the `DATE` to midnight (`00:00:00`) and then use this in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*),
       TRUNC( lastmodified )
FROM   leadextensions
GROUP BY TRUNC( lastmodified )
ORDER BY TRUNC( lastmodified )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `GROUP BY`.  You need to repeat the expression in Oracle:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), TRUNC(CAST(LASTMODIFIED AS DATE))
FROM LEADEXTENSIONS
GROUP BY TRUNC(CAST(LASTMODIFIED AS DATE))
ORDER BY TRUNC(CAST(LASTMODIFIED AS DATE)) DESC;
```

Although you are truncating the date in the `SELECT`, your version is still using the original value for the `GROUP BY`.